# C++. Bug with std::string::substr?

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, ascii, substr

I've been working with C++, and have used `std` library; specially, the method `string::substr`.

I have detected some errors in this method that I want to tell you.

1. For a string `abcñ`, a call to `substr(0, 4)` returns `abc?`.
2. For a string `abcç`, a call to `substr(0, 4)` returns `abc?`.
3. For a string `abcñd`, a call to `substr(0, 5)` returns `abcñ`.
4. For a string `abcçd`, a call to `substr(0, 5)` returns `abcç`.

I have noticed with these tests, that strange characters (such as `ñ` or `ç`), take up a double size. But, shouldn't `string::substr` keep this fact in mind, or work with different codifications? In the [API](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), there is no method to work with different codifications.

Comment: are you aware of std::string is std::basic_string<char>  and std::wstring is std::basic_string<wchar_t>? Also this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string makes it clear that substr is member of std::basic_string class and not std::string

Comment: Then should I work with wstrings in case of the use of these strange characters?

Comment: std::string is just an array of bytes. It is not an array of Unicode characters. Find some documentation about encodings, especially UTF-8.

Comment: yes, you should use std::wstring and make sure you tell the compiler that your literal is made by wide chars.

Comment: On the contrary, I recommend you use std::string and UTF-8, because UTF-8 is simpler and more efficient than UCS-2 ([read this](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/9/ucs-vs-utf8/)). Just be careful NOT to use functions such as substr because those functions are not character-wise, they are byte-wise. You have to use Unicode-aware functions.